# How can I lock my phone with a swipe lockscreen along with a fingerprint/PIN?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 running Android 5.0 on Verizon and would like to have my phone lock for 2-5 minutes with a swipe lockscreen after I sign in with my fingerprint or PIN. After the 2-5 minutes, I'd like the fingerprint or PIN prompt again.

I tend to bump my phone while it's in my pocket and the swipe lock screen prevents unintended actions, but I'd rather not like to put in my PIN or fingerprint multiple times in a short duration.

I had this feature with another S5 on AT&T running 5.1, but it seems that this is not the case on my current phone.

Is there anyway I can do this without using any lockscreen apps?

Comment: [Related XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/att-galaxy-s6/help/fingerprint-lock-swipe-to-unlock-t3128356)