# Allow fingerprint unlock but require password after a certain time limit

Tags: security, password, samsung-galaxy-s-8, fingerprint

Currently with a Samsung Galaxy S8, but I believe this is common to other devices, I can setup fingerprint unlock which requires a password when the device starts up or if I fail to scan my finger correctly a few times.

I would like to add another limitation: allow fingerprint unlock but require a password unlock every x minutes/hours or some other configurable time limit.

A somewhat silly scenario to illustrate the need: suppose I fall asleep on the train, I don't want anyone to be able to scan my finger and unlock my phone. I still want the comfort of unlocking the phone with my finger while knowing that after a while it will lock itself and require a password.

Is there a setting I'm missing or an app that can do that?

Following @beeshyams's answer, here are my current settings.

[image: settings screenshot 1]
[image: settings screenshot 2]
[image: settings screenshot 3]
[image: settings screenshot 4]

Comment: Related [Can I make Android require Fingerprint + PIN to unlock the screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/139653/131553)

Comment: If the solution didn't work for you and you can use Tasker, try solution linked above

Answer (score 1):

Samsung has its own ways of implementation so this may differ but stock implementation :

Fingerprint can unlock the phone after it goes to sleep ( Settings &radar; Display →  after xx minutes of inactivity) **only** if Power button is not used to lock *and* default lock screen is used

If you enable power button locking or any third party screen lock / launcher that can lock screen, you can't unlock with fingerprint. You require to enter PIN

That is a far more easier way of achieving what you want (though you can't configure the delay) going by the need in your example

If you really need a configurable interval, that *may* be possible but would surely need root

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. There's no difference if I lock the phone with the power key or just let it turn off after a minute. In both cases I can unlock with my finger. Even if it did work, I would'n just leave my screen on for a minute (or many minutes) because that would drain the battery and the phone might do stuff while unlocked in my pocket. I've added screenshots of my current settings.

Comment: As I said in the beginning, Samsung often does things differently. So the power - lock option is ruled out. Next you can try with a screen lock app of your choice or any other app, for instance I use Quick App lock which overrides default screen lock

Comment: How would you set this up with Quick App Lock? Suppose I want to be able to use my fingerprint to unlock the device as many times as I want, but have it require a password unlock after 30 minutes. Once I unlock with a password I can use fingerprint unlocks again for another 30 minutes.

Comment: That's not possible. The app I mentioned was an example of default screen lock being changed.. you may use any other app -just search for lock screen on Play store

Comment: Using such an app is to only ensure that you can only open with PIN always. Not use fingerprint + Configurable time lapse PIN